# SameSite None Cookie on Authentication Cookie On WordPress Website

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, cookies, iframe

I have a WordPress website which I want to embed in an iframe. As part of this, there is restricted content that redirects you to a login form if they are not logged into their account on my WordPress website.

This didn't use to be a problem. However, now on Chrome if I try and login through an iframe, the credentials are accepted but the authentication cookies don't appear to be set and so I just end up back at the login form (whereas on a regular Chrome tab it works and I can access the restricted content).

I believe this is because the WordPress authentication cookie itself is missing the SameSite=None attribute which means Chrome is seeing it as a 3rd party cookie and is therefore blocking it as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/01/get-ready-for-new-samesitenone-secure

However, unfortunately I can't seem to find a way of being able to set these properties onto my authentication cookies.

Steps I have tried so far:

1. Installing this WordPress Plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/samesite/ and following the instructions
2. Updating my PHP.ini settings with `session.cookie_secure = 1; session.cookie_httponly = 1; session.cookie_samesite = "None";` These settings were then confirmed to be on when using phpinfo(); but didn't seem to make a difference.

Is there anything else I can try or any obvious flaws with the two approaches I have tried so far?

If not, then is there an alternative way that I could manage logins that then wouldn't require cookies?

Comment: Are you getting any warnings related to cookies and their SameSite attribute, in the browser console? Is everything (main page, and your iframed WP) accessed via HTTPS?

Comment: Well when I look at some of the cookies they are highlighted yellow and have the following warning

"This cookie was blocked because its path was not an exact match for or a superdirectory of the request url's path"

However I assume this would be related to the issue at hand if the SameSite flag isn't being set to None?

Comment: WP doesn't use the PHP session mechanism, so what you tried under 2.) can't have any relevant effect here.

Comment: _"or any obvious flaws"_ - asking users to login within an iframe - where they can't verify _what_ they are actually logging in to via the browser address bar - is quite bad to begin with, IMHO. You're basically "training" the common sense & caution users should apply, to protect themselves from phishing sites, out of them ...